# PHP - array to URI

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, uri

I need to convert a multidimensional array to URI.

E.g.

```
$array[] = 'apple';
$array[] = 'banana';
$array[] = 123;
```

has to be converted to `array[]='apple'&array[]='banana'&array[]=123`

Note that there is no key inside the brackets.

Do you know any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Just curious, why you want to do that? You can serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a key inside the brackets, even if you don't specify one.  The code you provided will do the same as the following:

```
$array[0] = 'apple';
$array[1] = 'banana';
$array[2] = 123;
```

The brackets would not be valid values in a URL.  You can `serialize()` the array like this:

```
$url = "http://mypage.com?values=" . urlencode( serialize( $array ));
```

When you get it back on the server side, you can retrieve it like this:

```
$url = unserialize( $_GET['url'] );
```